# Convert RSA Private CRT Key to key file

Tags: rsa, certificate

Using the command `openssl rsa -in Alice.key -text -inform PEM -noout`, it is possible to view a RSA private key's data. My question is that if I have a list of all of the properties `(modulus, public exponent, private exponent, primeP, PrimeQ, primeExponentP, primeExponentQ, and crtCoefficient)` how would I convert that to a .key file that starts with `MII`

Comment: The *MII* value that you stated is the first part of the BASE64 encoding of the key. To build the RSA key from its values you could use some cryptographic library. 1) Import the data into a key object 2) Export the key object to a binary form 3) Convert the binary key into BASE64 or PEM encoding.

Comment: So we need more information on what exactly it is you are looking for. Are you looking for programming advice how to do the conversion? Are you asking how to do the conversion on the command-line? Are you asking how the latter format is defined so that you can figure the programming part out yourself? Depending on your answer to this, your question may need to be moved to a different site of the network (which I'll do no-problem).

Comment: A PEM file does not ever start with MII. It starts with a header line `-----BEGIN $type-----`, followed sometimes (rarely) by 822-style headers, _then_ (always) base64 with linebreaks, and a trailer line. Yes, it matters. Plus there are 4 different PEM formats supported by OpenSSL for RSA privatekey of which 3 are almost certain to have the base64 begin with MII, namely PKCS1 PKCS8-clear and PKCS8-encrypted, and commandline `rsa` can read all of them; which one (or ones) do you want?